# Why isn't Jane Doe's face covered in tattoos?

Tags: character, analysis, blindspot

In the series *[Blindspot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4474344/)*, Jane Doe's body is covered from her top to her feet except for her face. Why wasn't her face tattooed by the bad guy?

I can understand that they left her face untouched to make the series look better, I can't think of a woman with her face covered in tattoos that would make a good series, she looks more attractive this way. But would a theory like this be the reason why they didn't tattoo her face? Or was there a specific reason that her face wasn't tattooed?

Comment: I thought she *had* tattoos on her face but they're invisible (and revealed under UV light).

Comment: @Walt Osnap I didn't get that far yet in the series XD spoiler :D

Comment: Well, sorry about that, but you *did* ask... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going throughout the series and as **Walt** said (spoiler):

> She had tattoos on her face but they're invisible (and revealed under UV light).